# SwiftUI List view different cells for different indexes

Tags: swiftui

Let's say I want to have a different cell layout for some rows. Is there an easy way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Yes. But you'll need to provide a definition of "some rows". The answers differ depending on that.*

List's job is primarily to create a column of rows. But none of them actually have to be repeated.

```swift
var body: some View {
  List {
    Text("1")
      .background(Color.yellow)

    ForEach(2...5, id: \.self) {
      Text("\($0)")
        .background(Color.purple)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's say the first row will be different from the rest.

Comment: Done. That do it?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm facing another issue, but this seems to be working for now.

Comment: @p.dotor If you feel this answer helped please accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)